# Jquery: send user selections

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using this multi-select jquery plugin: http://loudev.com/#usage

My code is simple and it works (see below), my only problem is when I click the submit button, I do not get the values of the selected items, all I get is the submit button in $_POST.

How do I get the values from the SELECT box?

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>



    <link href="css/multi-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.multi-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="ryanTest.php">

<select id='custom-headers' multiple='multiple'>
  <option value='elem_1'>elem 1</option>
  <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
  <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
  <option value='elem_4'>elem 4</option>

  <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="sub" id="sub" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
$('#custom-headers').multiSelect({
  selectableHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selectable items</div>",
  selectionHeader: "<div class='custom-header'>Selection items</div>",
  selectableFooter: "<div class='custom-header'>Selectable footer</div>",
  selectionFooter: "<div class='custom-header'>Selection footer</div>"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try: <select name="custom-headers[]" ....

Comment: Perfect! Make an answer below so that I can accept it please!

Comment: Done added an answer for future reference and explained a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a name attribute.

```
<select id='custom-headers' name="custom-headers" multiple='multiple'>
```

suffix [] at the end of the name is for PHP, has no HTML use. If you use PHP:

```
   <select id='custom-headers' name="custom-headers[]" multiple='multiple'>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add attribute "name" in SELECT tag:
e.g.

and submit form, as you doing.

Hope this help